# Response.Redirect - Application_EndRequest

Tags: .net, response.redirect

I have a weird behavior in my app's prod environment. Prod env has 3 servers and in one of the servers, page redirection causes the Application_EndRequest event to be fired; other two works as expected. I want to avoid the EndRequest event to be fired on page redirect. I am using Response.Redirect(url). I tried using Response.Redirect(url, false); HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); Both of them triggers the Endrequest event. I am not sure whether its specific to that server alone.

The real problem is key session variables are reset when the application starts over again during Response.Redirect is executed which causes the application to error out. Is there a way to find the real cause of this problem? I am trying to solve this for past two days but no success.

My Prod severs are 64bit.

Can anyone help in this regard? Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks. ~/Ananth

Comment: When you say "application starts over" do you mean the AppDomain is recycled?  Because if that's the case, I would look into what's causing that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misreading the documentation (which is possible), I would say it functions as designed.

> [Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28VS.80%29.aspx)  calls End  which raises a ThreadAbortException  exception upon completion.

and

> [**HttpResponse.End Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
>   Sends all currently buffered output to the client, stops execution of the page, and raises the EndRequest  event.

and

> [**HttpApplication.EndRequest Event**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
>   Occurs as the last event in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution when ASP.NET responds to a request.

You say "redirect here."  ASP.NET writes the appropriate header to the stream.  Request is done, EndRequest should execute.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able to get around the problem by mirroring the complete setup from another prod server. Anyway, thanks for your reply. §Ananth

Comment: @Ananth: If you track down what was causing the AppDomain to reset you should post it in case someone else runs into the same problem.